# Python finding words in folder and save new files

Tags: python, cpu-word

I want to search a specific folder with files for words and then save the files with those words to another folder. I only get a blank new txt with my code. What might be wrong?

This is what I have:

```
from os import system, listdir, path
system("cls")
system("color b9")
FILE = open("CodeR.txt", "a")
desktop_dir = r"C:\Users\ilan\Desktop"
for fn in listdir(desktop_dir):
fn_w_path = path.join(desktop_dir, fn)
if path.isfile(fn_w_path):
    with open(fn_w_path) as filee:
        for line in filee:
            for word in line.lower().split():
                if word in {"user", "password", "username",             "pass",
                            "secret", "key", "backdoor", "ip"}:
                    FILE.write(word + "\n")
FILE.close()
```

Comment: For starters your indentation is wrong..is it only on the code posted here?

Answer (score 1):

You should try the following modified code:

```
from os import system, listdir, path
system("cls")
system("color b9")
FILE = open("CodeR.txt", "w")  # Should use "w" as write file 
desktop_dir = path.join("C:", "Users", "ilan", "Desktop")  # Should use path.join to create paths
for fn in listdir(desktop_dir):
    fn_w_path = path.join(desktop_dir, fn)
    if path.isfile(fn_w_path):
        with open(fn_w_path, "r") as filee:  # Should use "r" as read file
            for line in filee.readlines():  # Should use readlines() method. It give a list with lines.
                for word in line.lower().split():
                    if word in ["user", "password", "username",             "pass",
                            "secret", "key", "backdoor", "ip"]:  # Convert it to list. 
                        FILE.write(word + "\n")
FILE.close()
```

NOTE:
Copy files:

```
import os
import shutil

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("test_dir1", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        current_file = os.path.join(root, name)
        destination = current_file.replace("test_dir1", "test_dir2")
        print("Found file: %s" % current_file)
        print("File copy to: %s" % destination)
        shutil.copy(current_file, destination)
```

Output:

```
>>> python test.py 
Found file: test_dir1/asdf.log
File copy to: test_dir2/asdf.log
Found file: test_dir1/aaa.txt
File copy to: test_dir2/aaa.txt
```

Check folders:

```
>>>ll test_dir1 
./
../
aaa.txt
asdf.log

>>>ll test_dir2
./
../
aaa.txt
asdf.log
```

Comment: Thank you but it says it can’t find the C:\ folder when I use your tip? Also, how can I save the files with the keywords to another folder?

Comment: When you open the file to write, you can define the path of your file. In your case the CodeR.txt file will be create the location where you run python from : `FILE = open("CodeR.txt", "w")` . If you want to change the location of new file then you can do it like:  `FILE = open("C:\\temp_folder\\CodeR.txt", "w")`. Of course the path has to be existing and Python will create your file automatically.

Comment: Thanks it worked sort of, it saves a file where I want it but it is blank although I know the keywords are in the read files. Does this code really go through all files in the folder?

Comment: If you want to walk through all files and create the full path of them I suggest `os.walk()` method instead `os.listdir()` and `os.path.isfile()`. You can get all files recursively with this method. You can see details here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm . On the other hand you can get all files in a specific directory (In this case `C:\Users\ilan\Desktop`) with current implementations.

Comment: Can’t get it to work, still writes an empty txt as result. How can I move those files with keywords to another folder? Ex it found 15 files and I want to move them all to a result folder?

Comment: You should use `shutil` module for file copying. Examples: https://www.guru99.com/python-copy-file.html

Comment: Thanks but how can I copy all of the result files? Sorry I’m new to this.

Comment: I have updated my comment and added an example to copy files to another folder. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A last q though, what if only want to search for my keywords from row 4-20 in each file?

Comment: `for root, dirs, files in os.walk("test_dir1", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        current_file = os.path.join(root, name)
        with open(fn_w_path, "r") as filee: 
            for line in filee.readlines():  
                for word in line.lower().split():
                    if word in ["user", "password", "username",             "pass",
                            "secret", "key", "backdoor", "ip"]:
                                 # Here you can do with files which contain one of your keywords. current_file variable contains the path of related file`

Comment: Strange it still does not find any words for me. It writes an empty result file. Is this code for python 3? How would the whole code look like including only reading rows 4-20?

Answer (score 0):

The code has indentation problem. Also, you perform 
`for word in line.lower().split():`

lower and check here however,

`if word in {"user", "password", "username", "pass","secret", "key", "backdoor", "ip"}:`

you don't perform lower and then check here.

Might be you have to do

`if word.lower() in {"user", "password", "username", "pass","secret", "key", "backdoor", "ip"}:`.